# Ассоциативный массив в сессии Laravel

Tags: laravel

Помогите разобраться.

У меня есть ассоциативный массив в сесии.

```
$request->session()->push('productInfo', [
            'productId' => $request->get('productId'),
            'productAmount' => $request->get('productAmount', 1) + 1,
        ]);
```

При добавлении нового продукта, в массив productInfo добавляется новый элемент с ключём.

Как мне удалить товар из массива productInfo, чтобы не привязываться к номеру ключа?

```
$request->session()->forget('productInfo.0');
```

Не подходит такой вариант, так как привязка к ключу.

Или может можно как-то создать в массиве productInfo элемент с ключём, который я укажу?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свой вопрос следующим образом.

Я сделал обычный массив id-product. Просто при добавлении и увеличении товара добавляю несколько одиннаковых id